# how to add folders in subdirectory in java?

Tags: java, io, java-io

[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ya8y.png)

```
 `String pathname = "C:/sata1/pm8/data/pmin/";`
    String year ="UNKNOWN";
    year = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    String yearM = "UNKNOWN";
    yearM = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM").format(new Date());
    String yearD ="UNKNOWN";
    yearD =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());
    pathname+=year+"/"+yearM+ "/"+yearD;
    File directory;
    directory = new File(pathname);
    if (!directory.exists()){
        directory.mkdirs();
    }
```

This is what I tried. This makes the directory and subdirectory like this
`C:\sata1\pm8\data\pmin\2017\201709\20170919`. Now I have to make the 4 folders under `20170919`.

```
Directory(sata1) 
└── subDirectory(pm8) 
      └── subDirectory(data) 
            └── subDirectory(pmin) 
                  └── subDirectory(year) 
                    └── subDirectory(yearM) 
                        └── subDirectory(yearD) 
                                  ├── folder1 
                                  ├── folder2 
                                  └── folder3  like this
```

Comment: what error you face in your code?

Comment: you should create all directories that are absent step by step

Comment: @РоманДанилов no, you don't. mkdirs creates all directories.

Comment: i had created upto yearD subdirectory after that in yearD only i have to create the 4folder ?so hw can i do this

Comment: You seem to know how to make folders. What is the difficulty with making three more folders?

Comment: it is 3 folder in same directory as im making same its not creating all three folder in same subdirectory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sample program to make directories in java.
You can take it as reference and make program to create directories with name current year, current month, current day.

- First take current date using java.util.Date
- Then perform some string operation in date to get names of directories.
- And do some changes in this code as per your need.

  ```
  // shows how to create multiple directories in java
  // (multiple directory levels)
  public class JavaCreateMultipleDirectoriesExample
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      // the folders "000/111/222" don't exist initially
      File dir = new File("/Users/al/tmp/000/111/222");

      // create multiple directories at one time
      boolean successful = dir.mkdirs();
      if (successful)
      {
        // created the directories successfully
        System.out.println("directories were created successfully");
      }
      else
      {
        // something failed trying to create the directories
        System.out.println("failed trying to create the directories");
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: thanx raj i had already made the directory i have to make folder in last directory

Comment: i had added the reference

Comment: @Niti Kapoor so you need to check for last directory right, you can do with this code eg.
**File dir1 = new File("/Users/al/tmp/000/111/folder1");
File dir2 = new File("/Users/al/tmp/000/111/folder2");
File dir3 = new File("/Users/al/tmp/000/111/folder3");
 boolean successful = dir1.mkdirs();**

Comment: Ya i understand this but i had make the last directory in string so i m doing like this File dir1 =newFile("/pathname/cuts").mkdirs(); buts it doesnot show any folder

Comment: it is k if i had to add newFile("//sata1/pm8/data/pmin/scans/cuts").mkdirs(); its k if i had to add after pmin but i have to add after yearD and that is made recursive and added to pathname+=pathname+=year+"/"+yearM+ "/"+yearD

Answer (score 0):

I made it by making different directories each time.

```
String pathname1 = "C:";
String db = "db";
pathname1 += find2 + "/" + db;
System.out.println(pathname1);
File directory1 = new File(pathname1);
if (!directory1.exists()) {
    directory1.mkdirs();
}
String pathname2 = "C:";
String ocr = "ocr";
pathname2 += find2 + "/" + ocr;
System.out.println(pathname2);
File directory2 = new File(pathname2);
if (!directory2.exists()) {
    directory2.mkdirs();
}
String pathname3 = "C:";
String output = "output";
pathname3 += find2 + "/" + output;
System.out.println(pathname3);
File directory3 = new File(pathname3);
if (!directory3.exists()) {
    directory3.mkdirs();
}
String pathname4 = "C:";
String scans = "scans";
pathname4 += find2 + "/" + scans;
System.out.println(pathname4);
File directory4 = new File(pathname4);
if (!directory4.exists()) {
    directory4.mkdirs();
}
```